# How to use Jackson's JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubType annotations?

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, deserialization

**TL,DR** What arguments should I use on the annotations? Jump to **part 3**.

I've been struggling with the "not so good documentation" of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) , namely with respect to deserialization. Because of this, and I'm sorry for a long long post, I have some implementation details that I have to work around by myself with annotations (and there's a constraint of cannot build a [implementation TypeResolverBuilder](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)).

**NOTE:** the Jackson version is a 2.X (FasterXML).

Going straight to the point, I have different JSON requests that I must interpret (part 1) and match them against a data model (part 2). I know that I can use @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubType annotations but I'm having a bad time trying to understand it, that's why I'm reaching out to you with a full example.

### 1. JSON to be deserialized

I want to post this three different objects:

```
{ "animal" : {
  "dog" : {
    "name" : "Rex",
    "owner" : "Mike",
    "breed" : {
      "lab" : {
        "color" : "YELLOW",
        "family" : {
          "id" : null,
          "shortName" : "GL of NE",
          "longName" : "Great Labs of New England"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

.

```
{ "animal" : {
  "dog" : {
    "name" : "Rocky",
    "owner" : "Bruce",
    "breed" : {
      "goldenRetriever" : {
        "lifeSpan" : 15            
      }
    }
  }}
```

.

```
{ "animal" : {
  "bird" : {
    "color" : "BLUE"
  }}
```

### 2. Java data model

Then we have this model I want to match the JSONs against.

```
    abstract class Animal {
        private String _specie;
        // usual getters and setters...
     }

     class Bird extends Animal {
        private Color _color;

        public Bird(Color color) {
            super();
            this._color = color;
         }
         // + usual getters and setters...
     }

     class Dog extends Animal {
        private String _name;
        private String _owner;
        private Breed _breed;

        public Dog(String dogName, String dogOwner, Breed dogBreed) {
            super();
            this._name = dogName;
            this._owner = dogOwner;
            this._breed = dogBreed;
        }
        // + usual getters and setters...
    }

    abstract class Breed {
        private String _breedName;
        // usual getters and setters...
    }

    class Lab extends Breed {
        private Color _color;
        private Family _family;

        public Lab(Color color, Family family) {
            super();
            this._color = color;
            this._family = family;
         }
        // + usual getters and setters...
    }

    class GoldenRetriever extends Breed {
        private Integer _lifeSpan;

        public GoldenRetriever(Integer lifeSpan) {
            super();
            this._lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
         }
        // + usual getters and setters...
    }

    class Family {
        private String _id;
        private String _longFamilyName;
        private String _shortFamilyName;
         // usual getters and setters...
     }

     enum Color {
        BLUE("BLUE"),
        YELLOW("YELLOW"):
        private final _colorName:
        public colorName() {
            return this._colorName;
         }
    }
```

### 3. How to handle the annotations

The main questions here are,

1. On @JsonTypeInfo what parameters should I use to interpret something

   ```
   { ... {"dog": ... "breed" : { "lab" : { ... }}}}
   ```

   (use "lab" as a wrapper?). Or should it be on @JsonSubType?
2. How should I declare the Color class's annotation so I can match it only with "color" : "BLUE"?
3. Where and when should I be using @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty annotations?
4. What does "use", "include" and "property" mean on @JsonTypeInfo? Example @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@class") And how they affect the JSON deserialization?

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? because I'm having a similar issue; seems like a fairly common problem

Comment: @user26270: first I found this article [link](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html). Then I decided to use the following annotations on the top of the main class: `@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "family")
 @JsonSubTypes(value = {
  @Type(value = AConcreteSubClass.class),
  @Type(value = OtherConcreteSubClass.class)
 })`

Hope it helps. ;)